# I accidentally made my file system read only. How can I change it back?

Tags: mount, filesystem, permissions

I accidentally locked my Ubuntu System. Now everything is read only. The closest i can remember which might have done this is, I was trying to change the authority of a fstab symllink with `chown -h myusername /db`. Now everything is read only, file system, mounted volume, all except my home folder. Even when i open the file browser as admin i.e. sudo nautilus i can't create and change any file or folder.

What might have caused this? Help me turn things back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've accidentally changed the permissions of `/etc/fstab`. You should be able to use `sudo` because `/var/run/sudo` is mounted on the `/var/run` filesystem (or `/run` for Oneiric and up).

First, make the root partition writable again:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

Next, restore the permissions:

```
sudo chown root: /etc/fstab
```

After that, future boots should not make everything read-only.

Comment: Ok, the filesystem and new mounts are working, but the previously mounted drives and thumb drive are still read only. How to fix them.

Comment: Use `mount` to find the mount points and use the remount trick from the answer.

Comment: I hope I know how to?, I `umount` the drive, and tried this syntax, `sudo mount /dev/sda5 -o removount,rw /`, but it didn't work

Comment: Can you tell me how to find the mount points?

Comment: Run the command `mount`. Really, without any options, it prints mounted filesystems.

Comment: Can you tell me the command for it?

Comment: Just run `mount` without any options.