# How to remount a drive as rewritable?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, mount, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I accidentally made my file system read only. How can I change it back?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71430/i-accidentally-made-my-file-system-read-only-how-can-i-change-it-back)

Whenever I mount some of my partitions from the computer menu, they are mounted as read only and I want to fix it. As per the the help doc and a previous answer from another question I tried with command mount `/dev/sda5 -o remount-rw /media/mydrive`, but this didn't work.

Comment: If it's a ntfs partition: install ntfs-config and enable write support with this app.

Comment: @Jonathan Those drives became read only, due to reasons explained in this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71430/i-accidentally-made-my-file-system-read-only-how-can-i-change-it-back), so may be better way to fix this problem

Comment: @Jonathan, I downloaded the app, but how to use it. It give gtk warning all over "unable to find theme engine pixmap"

Comment: The command is `mount -o remount,rw /media/mydrive` with a comma, not a dash. This question is essentially a duplicate of your other question so I'm closing it.